# C言語で配列をポインタに、ポインタをレジスタにするプログラム

Tags: c, array, ポインタ

数字を指定された範囲内でランダムに発生させ、select_sortで小さい順に並べるプログラムを作成しています。配列のプログラムは作成できたのですが、それをポインタやレジスタにする方法がわかりません。
下記に示すのがそのプログラムです：

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 800000
#define RandMax 1000

void select_sort(int a[], int n){ /*ランダムで発生した数字を小さい順に並べ替える*/
    int i, j, min, t;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        min = i;
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        if (a[j] < a[min])
        min = j;
        t = a[min];
        a[min] = a[i];
        a[i] = t;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[MAX], i;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    a[i] = rand()%RandMax;
    for  (i=0; i<1000; i++){
        select_sort(a, MAX);
    }

    printf("data size = %d\n", MAX);

    /*for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        printf("%5d", a[i]);
        if (i%10 == 9)
        printf("\n");
    }*/
}
```

void select_sortから下のfor文を書き換えればできるとのことですが、どう書き換えればいいのかわかりません。教えてください。

例文として、配列

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int a[10], i, max;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) a[i]=rand()%100; 
    max=0;
    for(i=1; i<10; i++){
        if(a[max] < a[i])
    max=i; 
    }
for(i=0; i<10; i++) 
    printf("a[%d]= %d \n", i, a[i]);
    printf("max = %d, a[max]=%d \n", max, a[max]);
}
```

を以下のポインタのように書き換えれば、一つ目のプログラムも実行可能との指示を受けました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int a[10];
    int *i;
    int *max;
    int *last;
    last=a+10;
    for(i=a; i<last; i++)*i = rand()%100;
    max=a;
    for (i=a; i<last; i++){
        if(*max<*i)
        max=i;
    }
    for (i=a; i<last; i++)
    printf("a[%ld]=%d \n", i-a, *i);
    printf("max=%ld, a[max]=%d \n", max-a, *max);
}
```

Comment: 「ポインタやレジスタにする」とのことですが、質問者さんは「ポインタ」や「レジスタ」をどういうものと考えていて、何をしようとしているのでしょうか？

Comment: ポインタは変数アドレスを記憶する変数、つまりメモリ先のアドレスを取得してメモリから再び読み込む作業を減らすとは理解しているのですが、使い方があまりわかりません。またレジスタの場合、メモリに保存されている配列を読み込むのではなく、レジスタ変数を用いてCPU上に割り当ててそこから読み込むということも理解しています。やりたいこととしては、メモリを読み込んでプログラムを動かすという時間を少なくすると行ったことが目的です。

Comment: 頭が昭和なプログラミングの先生に指示されたとでも言うのなら仕方ありませんが、現在のCコンパイラはそこら辺のことは最適化のフェーズで人間よりも上手くやってくれます。適当に自分でポインタを使ったり`register`を指定しても、それに勝てることは滅多にありません。そのようなミクロな最適化を手作業で行うことに時間を使うより、アルゴリズムの勉強やライブラリの使い方を覚えられた方が良いように思います。ミクロなレベルの話をするなら、`for`や`if`は必ず`{}`と一緒に使うとか、適切なインデントを心がける、変数は使用する直前に宣言する、と言った最近のC言語のコーディングルールを覚えられた方が良いです。そのうちの一部はコンパイラの最適化にも寄与します。それと、投稿時に間違えたのかもしれませんが、現在のあなたのコード、`select_sort`は正しく動きません。レジスタなんて現在ではほとんど意味のないことを考える前に`select_sort`のどこが悪いのかを自分で見つけられるようになりましょう。

Comment: @WAWAWA  このコードでポインタを用いても計算時間が減ることはない筈ですが、ポインタの使い方を教えて欲しいという質問ですか？

Comment: Liamovwvさんも指摘されていますが、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/4236)に陥っていませんか？ 「ポインタやレジスタにする方法」が本当に解決したい問題、回答を募りたい内容なのですか？

Comment: @Liamovwv 使い方、というよりもポインタへの書き換え方でしょうか。例文のようにfor文の中の配列をポインタのようなソースコードに書き換えるという指示を受けているのですが、どのようにやればいいのかわからないと言った現状です。

Answer (score 1):

### 概要

- `select_sort`の書き換え方が分からないという質問だと解釈したので、とりあえず動くコードにしました。
- 主な原因は`select_sort`の２つ目のforの中が`i++`になってて、無限ループに陥ってることです。
- 「ポインタやレジスタにする方法」の部分は分からなかったのですが、`select_sort`の部分は本質を変えないでこれ以上実行時間を減らすことは無理だと思います。
- 本質とは関係ないですが、今回のソートアルゴリズムはO(n^2)なので、n=800000だと１回実行するだけでも凄まじい時間がかかります（6400秒くらい？）。そのため、以下のコードではn=800としています。デバッグでは問題サイズを小さくして繰り返し試せるようにしましょう。今後プログラマとしてやってく上で大事なことなので。

### コード

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 800
#define RandMax 1000

void select_sort(int a[], int n){ /*ランダムで発生した数字を小さい順に並べ替える*/
    int i, j, min, t;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        min = i;
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if (a[j] < a[min]){
                min = j;
                t = a[min];
                a[min] = a[i];
                a[i] = t;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[MAX], i;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)a[i] = rand()%RandMax;
    for  (i=0; i<1000; i++){
        select_sort(a, MAX);
    }

    printf("data size = %d\n", MAX);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        printf("%5d", a[i]);
        if (i%10 == 9)
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### 出力

```
data size = 800
    4    5    7   10   11   11   12   12   14   14
   15   16   16   18   20   20   22   25   29   33
   33   35   39   40   40   41   42   43   44   45
   47   49   50   53   54   54   55   56   56   58
   58   59   59   60   61   62   62   65   66   69
   70   70   73   75   76   76   77   80   80   83
   83   87   87   88   89   90   91   94   97   99
   99  103  103  104  105  106  108  109  109  110
  111  112  113  114  117  117  118  119  120  121
  123  124  127  127  128  128  129  130  130  130
  131  132  132  132  132  133  133  134  137  138
  139  139  140  142  144  144  145  146  146  147
  147  147  147  151  153  154  158  159  160  160
  162  162  163  164  165  166  166  166  166  167
  168  168  168  173  173  174  177  181  181  184
  184  190  194  195  196  198  201  201  207  209
  211  211  211  213  213  213  214  217  220  223
  225  227  227  228  229  231  232  234  234  234
  235  236  239  240  242  242  243  243  245  248
  249  250  251  253  256  258  258  261  261  262
  262  264  265  265  266  269  269  271  271  272
  279  283  283  284  286  287  290  291  291  291
  292  293  294  296  296  297  297  299  299  300
  301  301  302  302  306  310  310  311  312  314
  316  318  319  319  319  321  322  322  325  327
  328  329  330  330  331  332  333  334  334  336
  338  338  341  344  345  345  345  346  347  347
  349  349  351  354  355  356  360  360  361  361
  361  362  364  364  365  366  368  371  372  372
  373  373  375  376  379  379  380  382  384  385
  385  386  387  387  388  389  389  390  390  391
  392  394  395  395  397  398  400  401  402  402
  404  405  406  407  408  408  409  409  409  412
  412  413  413  413  414  414  414  415  416  417
  417  421  421  422  425  427  429  430  430  435
  436  438  439  439  440  443  444  445  445  446
  448  450  451  454  455  455  457  460  461  461
  463  463  463  464  465  467  469  472  472  474
  475  476  476  481  484  491  491  492  494  496
  496  496  496  496  497  497  501  502  503  504
  504  505  506  507  510  511  516  517  518  519
  519  520  520  521  521  522  523  526  526  527
  530  531  535  535  535  540  540  545  546  546
  547  547  548  549  553  553  556  557  559  563
  564  565  565  566  568  570  571  572  575  580
  580  581  581  583  584  585  585  587  589  589
  589  590  592  592  598  598  599  602  603  604
  606  608  610  611  612  615  617  617  617  619
  620  621  623  624  626  626  627  627  631  631
  631  632  633  633  637  640  640  643  645  645
  648  649  650  653  654  654  656  657  658  658
  660  661  662  662  663  664  664  664  664  665
  667  671  674  675  679  680  681  681  682  683
  683  685  686  686  688  688  688  689  690  694
  694  699  701  701  701  702  702  704  704  705
  706  706  706  707  709  709  709  710  711  711
  712  713  713  714  714  714  714  715  715  718
  719  719  723  724  724  725  727  728  732  732
  732  733  733  733  734  736  737  737  739  739
  740  740  741  742  744  744  745  746  747  747
  750  751  752  756  758  759  761  761  762  764
  765  765  767  767  768  769  769  769  772  773
  774  774  774  777  777  779  779  780  781  782
  783  783  785  785  785  787  789  790  790  793
  795  797  798  800  800  802  802  804  805  805
  805  805  805  807  808  809  809  809  809  810
  811  812  813  814  818  819  820  824  826  827
  827  827  829  831  831  832  832  833  833  834
  835  836  836  836  840  841  842  843  844  845
  846  846  846  849  849  852  853  853  853  858
  859  861  862  862  863  864  867  868  871  873
  874  876  877  878  880  881  881  883  883  884
  885  885  889  890  891  892  893  895  896  903
  904  905  907  907  908  908  911  911  913  914
  917  918  921  923  924  925  928  928  931  931
  932  935  935  935  936  938  938  940  940  940
  941  942  943  944  944  944  944  949  950  950
  950  953  958  958  958  959  960  960  961  965
  966  969  970  975  977  978  979  980  984  986
  988  989  991  992  992  995  995  996  996  998
```